# WordPress, Docker and nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker

Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I'm running WordPress as a standard install, i.e in /var/www/html. I also have a Discourse instance running in a Docker container, with port 8081 exposed. My intention is to have the WP instance at domain.com and Discourse on sub.domain.com. I've tried using nginx to intercept requests for sub.domain.com but it doesn't seem to be working - it just sends everything to domain.com. What have I done wrong?

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.domain.com:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sub.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sub.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   
  }
}
```

`localhost` may not necessarily resolve to `127.0.0.1` which is where your Docker container is listening.

Make sure you can get to port `8081` from your machine. Run:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8081
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: That did it. I also had a bad entry in ```/etc/hosts```. Thanks!

Comment: I can telnet to wordpress but when I load the site the browser is redirected to localhost